# How to write rows in CSV file DYNAMICALLY in python?

Tags: python, csv, dynamic

I want to create a csv file and write data to it dynamically my script have to keep running 24/7 and csv files have to be created and written every 24 hours, right now all files are created when the program ends.

```
with open(file_name, 'r+') as f:
    myDataList = f.readlines()
    nameList = []
    for line in myDataList:
        entry = line.split(',')
        nameList.append(entry[0])
    if name not in nameList:
        now = datetime.datetime.now()
        dtString = now.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(name, dtString)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Remove the file context. Use the earlier way of writing file. And keep doing flush() and fsync() on the file like shown below. That ensures that data is written to the file on disk.

```
f = open(FILENAME, MODE)
f.write(data)
f.write(data)
f.flush()  #important part
os.fsync(f) # important part
```

For more info: see [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsync)